# AWS Cloudwatch Log Metrics FilterPattern on XML text

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to add a filter to AWS Cloudwatch log on XML text that is printed to log file.

e.g. `<one> <Test>Something</Test> <Msg>blah blah</Msg></one>`

I am trying to put filter pattern on text `<Test>Something</Test>`. I have tried below options but none of them work. I receive "Invalid metrics filter pattern". There will be lines in the log file that will  not have this text as well.

`&lt;Test&gt;Something&lt;/Test&gt;`
`<Test>Something</Test>`
`<\"Test>\"Something<\"/\"Test>\"`

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but might help future visitors.
I got around by using [query inside Cloudwatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData_RunSampleQuery.html)

Example log generated in Cloudwatch

```
Timestamp: 2021-01-12T20:50:40.579+01:00

Message: 
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name='SubjectUserName'>-</Data>
        <Data Name='SubjectDomainName'>-</Data>
        <Data Name='SubjectLogonId'>0x0</Data>
        <Data Name='TargetDomainName'>NT AUTHORITY</Data>
        <Data Name='LogonProcessName'>NtLmSsp </Data>
        <Data Name='AuthenticationPackageName'>NTLM</Data>
        <Data Name='LogonGuid'>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
        <Data Name='TransmittedServices'>-</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

Query to find all events with `TargetDomainName=NT AUTHORITY`

```
// very simple regex
fields @message
| filter @message like /<Data Name='TargetDomainName'>NT AUTHORITY<\/Data>/
```